# @DataJpaTest failing to @Autowire CrudRepository and raising NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

**The setup:**

- a JPA `ReviewRepository` extending `CrudRepository<TEntity, TId>`
- My test uses the slice test annotation **`@DataJpaTest`**
- My test `@Autowired ReviewRepository repo`

**The problem:**

- My `@Autowired` fails and raises a **`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`** saying that there is no Bean qualified to be injected into my `ReviewRepository repo` field.

**Things I've tried:**

- With and without `@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppEntry.class)`
- With and without `@EnableJpaRepositories` in my **AppEntry** class

**The Error:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'boxfish.apis.youtube.channelDiscovery.reviews.domain.reviews.ReviewRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
```

**Code for `ReviewRepositoryTest.java`**

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppEntry.class)
@ActiveProfiles(INTEGRATION)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE)
@Transactional
public class ReviewRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ReviewRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void findOneByExpansionIdAndPartIdInAndType() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

**Code for `ReviewRepository.java`**

```java
public interface ReviewRepository extends CrudRepository<ReviewEntity, ReviewEntityId> {

}
```

**Code for `AppEntry.java`**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class AppEntry {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppEntry.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Spring Boot Auto Configuration Report**

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration#dataSourceInitializer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceConfiguration matched:
      - AnyNestedCondition 1 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.PooledDataSourceAvailable PooledDataSource found supported DataSource; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.ExplicitType @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'type' (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource,javax.sql.XADataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.TomcatDataSourcePoolMetadataProviderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.TransactionManagementConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (flyway.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayConfiguration#flywayInitializer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayConfiguration.FlywayInitializerJpaDependencyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean; SearchStrategy: all) found bean '&entityManagerFactory' (OnBeanCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration.FlywayJpaDependencyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean; SearchStrategy: all) found bean '&entityManagerFactory' (OnBeanCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - HibernateEntityManager found class 'org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager' (HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.HibernateEntityManagerCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration#jdbcTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration#namedParameterJdbcTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#transactionManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration NONE cache type (CacheCondition)

   TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration#testEntityManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration#platformTransactionManagerCustomizers matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'transactionManager' (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration#transactionTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   CacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheManagerJpaDependencyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   CaffeineCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine', 'org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'com.couchbase.client.spring.cache.CouchbaseCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - EmbeddedDataSource found supported pooled data source (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatDataSourceJmxConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jmx-enabled) did not find property 'jmx-enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Dbcp:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Dbcp2:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Generic:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'spring.datasource.type' (OnPropertyCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Hikari:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.CommonsDbcp2PoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.CommonsDbcpPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration#transactionManager:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'transactionManager' (OnBeanCondition)

   EhCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'net.sf.ehcache.Cache', 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (eureka.client.enabled) found different value in property 'eureka.client.enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClientConfig'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   GenericCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GenericCacheConfiguration NONE cache type (CacheCondition)

   GuavaCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance', 'com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   InfinispanCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.cache.Caching', 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration.JpaWebConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) not a web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean,org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension#0' (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration NONE cache type (CacheCondition)

   SimpleCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration NONE cache type (CacheCondition)

   TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration#dataSource:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.test.database.replace=AUTO_CONFIGURED) found different value in property 'replace' (OnPropertyCondition)

   TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration#embeddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.test.database.replace=ANY) found different value in property 'replace' (OnPropertyCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This problem is solved**

Not much later than the question was posted, I found the answer: my classpath was compromised. I had two natures enabled in my eclipse project (Spring STS and Gradle) and they following happened:

- Both plugins imported dependencies for Spring-JPA
- This has caused Spring Autoconfigurator to be confused about which Repository resolution routine to use and entered **strict mode**
- After that, my interfaces implementing CrudRepository would not receive an implementation coming from Spring Data JPA

**How have I found this?**

It was right there, under my nose, not in an error, but in a shy corner of the startup log (INFO):

```
14:26:40.729 [main] INFO  b.a.y.c.r.i.ReviewUpserIntegrationTest - The following profiles are active: integration
14:26:40.734 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7de4a01f: startup date [Thu Mar 02 14:26:40 GMT 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@130e116b
14:26:41.521 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
14:26:41.562 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport - Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface boxfish.apis.youtube.channelDiscovery.reviews.domain.reviews.ReviewRepository.
14:26:41.943 [main] WARN  o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
```

The line we are talking about is `Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!`

A good cleanup and de-activation of the natures in Eclipse have solved the problem:

- `gradle clean cleanEclipse eclipse build --refresh-dependencies` in the Shell
- Refresh of the project in eclipse